# capybara find <p> value with span text, xpath

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xpath, rspec, css-selectors, capybara

I am looking to select the paragraph value text from the below html.

```
<p><span class="field-label">First Name: </span>'Bob'</p>
```

I have come up with so far.

```
expect (find('span.field-label', text: 'First Name:').find(:xpath, './/..').text).to eq('Bob')
```

What would be the best way to target 'Bob'?

Is there a way to visually see where I am on the tree?

Comment: Can you change the html to make things more convenient?

Comment: Nope, we are locked into this html.

Comment: Then you are stuck with xpathing. You can make a single xpath statement to get Bob, but I can't provide one (xpath is a pain, I'd change the html)

Answer (score 1):

You try following.
expect(page).to have_css("p", :text => 'Bob')

Answer (score 0):

You can just expect the page to have have bob

```
expect(page).to have_content('Bob')
```

Comment: I have a couple instances of 'Bob' on this page.

Comment: Do you know which one you want?

Comment: I was hoping to encapsulate this type of logic into a helper method that I could then pass it the span.text and the desired value in order to validate the page contains the pairing.